# Multiple imputation in R with mice package

Tags: inference, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, pooling, mice

I have conducted a multiple imputation in R with 5 imputations and 50 iterations using the function `mice()` from the corresponding mice package.
Now that I have analysed and discussed all my results I have realised that the default settings of the `complete()` function is to choose the first imputed dataset out of five.
I did not know that I can choose which dataset I want to work with.
Is there a special reason why the default setting is to chose the first dataset and how can I ***argue*** that I did so?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using an imputed data set for analysis amounts to single imputation. The way you are using the package now, you are not performing multiple imputation. No single imputation can ever reflect the variance well, so I do not recommend choosing any particular imputed data set.

The power of `mice` is to combine the results of all your imputations. Using the function `pool`, you can combine estimates and standard errors of a whole set of fitted models (each fitted to a different imputation).

The main author of the `mice` package has written a very nice book that details how to correctly use it. You can find it here:

- Stef van Buuren (2018): [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/), 2nd ed.

You can also simply have a look at the examples in the package [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf), starting perhaps with the `pool` function.